# Angular 2 digest fails at executing a function, or finding a change at an object's property

Tags: angularjs, angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

I have absolutely no idea on what's going on; my two theories are already in the title. Thing is, this *should* be working, but somehow one of the core parts of Angular, the digest cycle, is failing hard.

**What I want to do, and how I did it**

A comments section that is instantiated in a parent view, when you click a button. Then the comments appear, and they behave similarly to Reddit's: you can upvote or downvote them. Pretty much the same! So I just added some  with the arrows, and the rating of the comments between them:

```
<div class="rating">
    <ion-row>
    <button class="nocolor" (click)="rateComment(comment, true)">
    <ion-icon large name="arrow-up" [color]="isRated(comment.rated, 1)"></ion-icon>
    </button>
    </ion-row>
     <ion-row>
     <span [style.margin-left]="pointsMargin(comment.rating)">{{comment.rating}}</span>
    </ion-row>
     <ion-row>
       <button class="nocolor" (click)="rateComment(comment, false)">
    <ion-icon large name="arrow-down" [color]="isRated(comment.rated, 2)"></ion-icon>
       </button>
    </ion-row>
</div>
```

As you can see, when I click in the icons, they execute the "rateComment" function, which is:

```
   rateComment(comment, liked){
     if (liked==true){
       comment.rating++;
       comment.rated=1;
       //register like
     }else{
       comment.rating--;
       comment.rated=-1;
       //register unlike
     }
   }
```

Ok, pretty straightforward. Now that the object's property is properly changed, we should somehow change the icon's color from the default gray-like color, to something more like amber. This works perfectly when the data is first represented: you see the voted comments with the proper arrow, proper colored. Great. **But if you click in the arrow, the color doesn't change**.

The function that chooses the color of the icon, which works good at start but fails when updating the view, is this one:

```
   isRated(value, component){
     if(component == 1 && value == 1){
       return 'amber';
     }else if(component == 2 && value == -1){
       return 'amber';  
     }
   }
```

Basically, as you can see, the upper arrow uses 1 as component value and the down arrow uses 2, just to reuse the function.

**So, what's the problem?**

As I already said, the problem I'm having here, is that either the "isRated" function is not being executed in the digest's cycle, or that the change os the ion-icon color is not working, or the property change of the object does not trigger a view update. I just don't know what's going on; but something is failing hard and I can't find any error in my code.

EDIT: the "isRated" function executed, BUT with the old value, like if the new one doens't get registered in the object. This is odd, since it actually gets changed in the "rateComment" function.

Comment: Have you put some logging in to see what's getting called and when?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I've seen if the object's property is properly changed, and it is. Also, when the isRated function is executed after the rateComment one, it works like if the properties haven't been changed... Something is really wrong here.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve], without seeing how it fits together it's hard to say what you're doing.